# $(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)$ divides $abc$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Do there exist pairwise distinct positive integers $a,b,c,d$ such that no two sum to another, and

- $(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)$ divides $abc$
- $(a+b-d)(b+d-a)(d+a-b)$ divides $abd$?

If we only require the first condition, then $a=7,b=10,c=18$ works. However, with two conditions I haven't been able to find anything by hand or computer.